# How to make ajax spinning animation center of parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the below html skeleton for a web page.

```
<div class="grand-parent">
    <div class="header">Heading</div>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="child-div-1">
        </div>
        <div class="child-div-2">
        </div>
        <div class="child-div-3">
        </div>
        <div class="ajax-loader-container">
            <div class="ajax-loader"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to make the spinning animation gif center of the `parent-div`. Also add a overlay on top the parent-div while spinning animation is displayed. How can I achieve it through css?

Below css I have tried, but not working as expected. It didn't show the overlay.

```
.ajax-loader-container {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999999999999999999;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    opacity: .8;
}

.ajax-loader {
    background: url(spinner.gif);
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to be showing/hiding the loader somehow, below is one way to get the position right. But bear in mind .ajax-loader-container will now be above your content.

```css
.parent-div{
  position: relative;
}

.ajax-loader-container {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999999999999999999;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    opacity: .8;
}

.ajax-loader {
    background: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
    <div class="header">Heading</div>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="child-div-1 child-div">
        </div>
        <div class="child-div-2 child-div">
        </div>
        <div class="child-div-3 child-div">
        </div>
        <div class="ajax-loader-container">
            <div class="ajax-loader"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PaulThoams GC tried this, but the .ajax-loader-container element is spanning entire .grant-parent class. I want to make the .ajax-loader-container class only span across the .parent-div element

Comment: Have you double checked that you have put 'position: reletive' on .parent-div and that .ajax-loader-container sites within .parent-div ? In my code snippet above, the result is exactly as you describe.